# How to add Windows Forms Application in visual studio c++ 2012

Tags: visual-c++

I excitedly installed Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop on my fresh Windows 8 installation a couple days ago. I opened it and quickly found, to my dismay, that there is no native support for a C++ Windows Forms Application.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct guide that worked for me.
http://www.gamedev.net/blog/909/entry-2254695-native-only-apps-with-vs-express-
for-win8/

It is a hack and it's not the "proper" experience you'd expect or be used to.
I'd recommend getting 2010 express

Looking into more it seems like MS has a Visual studio 2012 for desktop for windows 8
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/06/08/visual-studio-express-2012-for-windows-desktop.aspx

Comment: I edited my comment,  I pasted the wrong links in the other comment.

Comment: Updated my answer to show my findings, do some more research on what exactly is Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Desktop